# How to read data from excel template

Tags: c#

I have a excel template am taking it in a datatable i want to read the datatable and save it in database

my problem is data is not well aligned i want to insert data number wise for e.g set of 1 number data then process number 2 data.
i have two tables one for saving training details and other for participant

```
var dtsel = dataTable.Select();
```

i want to process this dtsel datatable.

Comment: You've got to at least attempt something, write some code and come back if you have questions.

Comment: What kind of database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

> i want to read the datatable and save it in database
>
> my problem is data is not well aligned

Then just go ahead and align your data in excel...

***One way to do so would be:***

1. Select all your columns in excel.
2. In data, select the from table/range

[image]

3. Select all your data, go to transform and select the fill down option

[image]

4. Your data should now be well aligned, save the new sheet.

[image]
 5. Now you can easily import the excel sheet to SQL server, MY SQL or other databases with built in tools

[Import data from Excel to SQL Server or Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-data-from-excel-to-sql?view=sql-server-2017)